# CSS set the margin of a div equal to another div's width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have these two classes that define a sidebar :

```
.w-sidebar {
    width: 250px;
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
}

.row.collapse {
    margin-left: -250px;
    left: 0;
}
```

The margin-left of the second must be equals the negative of the width of the first for it to work.

But then I wanted to make the width dynamic instead of a fixed pixel amount :

```
.w-sidebar {
    width: 35vw;
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 100vw;
}

.row.collapse {
    margin-left: -250px;
    left: 0;
}
```

How can I make the margin-left of the `.row-collapse` dynamic and equal to the width of the `.w-sidebar` using only css?

I tried using a mix of `min`/`max` inside a `calc` but that isn't supported.

Also tried using the media queries, but to be honest just found out about it and couldn't figure it out.

My fork/attempt : https://www.codeply.com/go/eUGo31Lwho

Working original demo : https://www.codeply.com/go/clX6THorTK

Answer (score 3):

What about CSS variables :

```css
:root {
  --v: 250px;
}

.box {
  width: var(--v);
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
}

.left {
  margin-left: calc(-1 * var(--v));
  width: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div><div class="left"></div>
```

Comment: This answers the title, but I don't know how to apply to my context, as the --v variable would also need to have a dynamic value

Comment: simply use it to add your value there instead of adding value to the width :)

Comment: @Mojimi or maybe you can show us your situation so we can see ?

Comment: @Mojimi yes i saw it and you only have a fixed value defined

Comment: No, It uses not only vh, but also a min size of 250px

Comment: @Mojimi - the only fixed width is 250px.. you can use a var for that. This answer explains how to get the negative value of the var (-250px) using calc(). What does that have to do with `vh`?

Comment: @ZimSystem Sorry I don't understand, there's two demos there, the original with fixed, and my try using vh, if you could put the answer using a fork of my forked codeply that would solve our misunderstanding.

Comment: @ZimSystem it's vw, I just mispelled, it is correct on the code and the question

Comment: There's 4 places where width is `250px` (or `-250px`) in the original. You just change those as desired. As @TemaniAfif said you can use a CSS variable: https://www.codeply.com/go/kLAHY3A09L

Comment: @ZimSystem right but the min width should be fixed 250px and max 100vw, in your codeply the min width is 35vw, and the only two classes to consider in the codeply are the ones in the question